# Is there an effective working method for having two git repositories separated by network file transfer, but not ssh/http?

Tags: git, push, pull

I have git repository **A** on machine **A** (which is in turn a clone of a "central" repository hosted by a development team). For various reasons, I don't like to develop on machine **A** (poor development tools), but instead I'd like to develop on machine **B**. The two are/can be connected by transferring files across the network (i.e. *virtual* sneakernet), but for various complicated firewall-related questions outside the scope of this question, I cannot connect them directly using ssh, http, or suchlike. Connecting a removable drive/USB stick etc. to machine **A** is not possible either.

Is there an easy way for me to clone the repository onto machine **B**, then develop on a local branch there with several commits, and once I'm done, move/push the changes from that branch onto a corresponding branch on machine **A** by transferring a single file, rather than connecting to a remote machine using `git push`/`git pull` etc.? In other words, can I keep them in sync with some kind of delta file/package file/etc.?

I have thought of flattening my changes on machine **B**, using `git rebase -i`, into one change, then passing over the diff, but I'd prefer to preserve my git history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`git bundle`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html).

> Some workflows require that one or more branches of development on one
>   machine be replicated on another machine, but the two machines cannot
>   be directly connected, and therefore the interactive git protocols
>   (git, ssh, rsync, http) cannot be used. This command provides support
>   for git fetch and git pull to operate by packaging objects and
>   references in an archive at the originating machine, then importing
>   those into another repository using git fetch and git pull after
>   moving the archive by some means (e.g., **by sneakernet**). As no direct
>   connection between the repositories exists, the user must specify a
>   basis for the bundle that is held by the destination repository: the
>   bundle assumes that all objects in the basis are already in the
>   destination repository.

Comment: +1 and I copied the description over your minimum-length complaint, hope that's ok

Answer (score 1):

You can [generate a single patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) on `B` with every commit from R1 to R2:

```
git format-patch master --stdout R1..R2 > big.patch
```

You can apply it on `A` like:

```
git am -3 big.patch
```

Comment: Thanks. This is close, but creates one large commit on A, which is what I already know how to do. I'm looking to preserve the history.

Comment: use `git am -3` instead of `git apply`. `git apply` is a low-level tool that does much the same thing as the classic `patch` util does; `am` is for easily creating individual commits.

Comment: `frrmat-patch` will preserve the individual commits ("Prepare each commit with its patch in one file per commit").  The `stdout ... > big.patch` places all of these patches in one file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realise, my apologies. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. Probably the easiest thing to do is to make another copy of your repository on your removable storage device of choice. Then you can add it as a remote and push and pull changes to and from it on both machines.

Comment: I should add that I cannot connect a removable storage device to machine A. But this is helpful to those who do find themselves in that scenario.